# How to use headers common for all api requests using service in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Iam working in angular4 ecommerce project.Here I need different api calls from backend having common headers with key and secret key.I have kept all the api urls in a service and whenever there is a api call,I am using that service.Here Iam declaring headers every time of api call.But I want to place those headers as global in that same service,so that I can use the headers too using that service.My problem is Iam unable use the headers in the service that are common to all api requests.How can I implement this one in angular?Please help me.Here is my code:
//service...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class SharedServiceService {
public static headers = new Headers();
    public static baseUrl='https://www.t3stores.com/mystores/wordpress/';
    public static baseUrl2='https://colourssoftware.com/T3Liquors/';
    public static newCollections=SharedServiceService.baseUrl+'wp-json/wc/v2/products?tag=882';
public static productsApi=SharedServiceService.baseUrl+'wp-json/wc/v2/products?page=1&per_page=100';
    public static products=SharedServiceService.baseUrl;
    }

    //headers:
      createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' +
            btoa('ck_543700d9f8c08268d75d3efefb302df4fad70a8f:cs_f1514261bbe154d662eb5053880d40518367c901'));
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }
     let headers = new Headers();
        this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for Interceptors in Angular .

of Interceptors

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class AngularInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).do(event => {}, err => {
        if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
            console.log("Error Caught By Interceptor");
            //Observable.throw(err);
            // instead of handling error you can add headers
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**To activate the interceptor**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [
        [ { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: 
              AngularInterceptor, multi: true } ]
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

More on [`Interceptors`](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services)

Comment: Here I need to use same headers for different api calls in different components.How can I implement this using interceptors?

Comment: This is what interceptor does. For all your different api calls this will act as an interceptor and you can add in your headers the example i gave was for headers you can take the req and append headers to it

Comment: ok.Is I need to add interceptors in headers?Actually where I have to declare those common headers?

Comment: You need to define the common headers in the interceptor. And clone the req and add the headers

Answer (score 0):

So here is how you would do it, as given above in Rahul's example you can define your interceptor that way. But you need to clone the request and add the header, see the example below that does it, In this example I have my service that gets the common headers, which is instantiated as mser.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private mser: myService) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const url: string = request.url;
    const method: string = request.method;
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'org-id': this.mser.feId,
        'source-id': this.mser.get().sourceId,
        'application-id': this.mser.get().applicationId,
        locale: this.mser.primaryLocale,
        uuid: uuid()
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

In order to do the setup for the interceptor you need to provide this in your provider array in your module.ts file. Something like given below,

```
provider :[  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyHttpInterceptor, multi: true }]
```

After you start the app and you try to hit any service you will find that code given in interceptor will be executed.

Alternatively you can setup the header information in hard coded manner also in which case you will have to remove the mser in my code example below and provide the hardcoded values instead.

Something like this,

```
request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            'org-id': 'MyHardcodedValue1',
            'source-id': 'MyHardcodedValue2',
            'application-id': 'MyHardcodedValue3',
            locale: 'MyHardcodedValue4',
            uuid: 'MyHardcodedValue5',
          }
        });
```